# See if username variable is empty and if so do not go to page2.php

Tags: php, html

I am creating a live chat website called meekochat. The user puts in their name on page1.php and then gets sent to page2.php to start talking with other people. I want to make so that if the username variable is empty then the user is not taken to page2.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

session_start();
?>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<title>meekochat</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<?php 


 ?>


 </head>

 <body id="body">

 <form action="page2.php" method="post">

 <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

</body>


</html>
```

This is my code for page2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<title>meekochat</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];

}

?>

</head>

<body id="body">

Your username is <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: One of several solutions is to check the values with Javascript before to send your request.

Comment: How  can I do that?

Comment: And what is your actual _question_? (Just telling us what you want, does not constitute a proper question.) Also, make up your mind whether you want the user to not be able to submit this form in the first place, if they did not fill out the field - or if you want to check this at the receiving end, and then _redirect back_ to the first page - those are two very different things as well.

Comment: check on both the client-side **and** the server-side. Even then, there are ways round it, but doing all you can on both sides heavily reduces the chances

Comment: Why not make another php file to check the name? so the form action in page1.php goes to auth.php, which then decides if the name exists or not and then redirect to the corresponding page.

Comment: You can't have HTML or whitespace or anything output before `session_start`

Comment: Thanks Rizki Hadiaturrasyid!

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid is a bit ott when you can do it before it even goes to another file. Having a file just to check isn't efficient

Comment: So do I check if the variable is empty on page1.php and if it isn't then go to page2.php but if it is then go to page1.php?

Comment: Or an even simpler way is just adding required to the html <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to keep the "auth" in page1.php. I added some validation and required attribute for the username input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && $_POST["username"] != '') {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
    header('location: page2.php');
}
?>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>meekochat</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="body">

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

and in the page2.php you just need to check if the user has an username

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '')
    header('location: page1.php')
?>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<title>meekochat</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body id="body">

Your username is <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in either PHP or Javascript.

#### PHP

If you want a PHP way you can set the header.

```
header('Location: www.example.com');
```

**Warning:** you can only use header if you haven't sent any other information to the client.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

#### Javascript

You can redirect the browser using the following:

```
window.location = "www.example.com";
```

This can be done at any time.

Sources: [PHP-Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) [JS-Window-Location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend w3schools - full of bad practice, MDN is a much better resource in days of late :)

Answer (score -1):

on page2.php you should check if username is empty too and if it is you should redirect to page1 with `header("Location")` or echo `<script>` tag with `window.location="your url"`

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])&&!empty($_POST["username"])) {

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"]; 

}
else
{
  header("Location:".  "http://yourwebsite.domain/page1.php"  );
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<title>meekochat</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="body">

Your username is <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it without Javascript is by making another php file to verify:

//verify.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"])){
        include("somepath/file2.php");
        }
    else{
        include("somepath/file1.php")
        }
?>
```

Or a simpler way, just add a required attribute in HTML

```
<input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the required attribute but i'm also going to use verify.php because someone could hit the spacebar once and get past it. (since one space means the input box is not technically empty the user can go to page2.php with no name. ).